# How can I change the toggle button to close button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change toggle btn onclick it to a close btn and hide .main-nav when click  close btn. please help me. thanks

```js
$(".toggles-menu").click(function(e){
    $(".main-nav").slideDown("slow");
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggles-menu "><i class = "material-icons rh-header-icon "  style = "color :  #ECF0F1; font-size : 30px ">menu</i></button>
```

Comment: I assume you want to change the `class` of the `<i>`? Like change `rh-header-icon` to some other icon?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
$(".toggles-menu").click(function(e){
    $(".main-nav").hide(); // changed this to hide
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggles-menu"><i   style = "color :  #ECF0F1; font-size : 30px "> x </i></button>



<div class="main-nav" style="background-color:yellow;text-align:center"> Main Nav</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using a class to denote the text displayed rather than having a static "Menu" in your content. You can then check whether the button contains the "active" or "inactive" class (using jQuery's .hasClass()) and perform changes to the DOM based on that, like this;

```
<button class="toggles-menu inactive"><i class = "material-icons rh-header-icon "  style = "color :  #ECF0F1; font-size : 30px ">menu</i></button>

$(".toggles-menu").click(function(e){
    $(".main-nav").slideDown("slow");
     if ($(".toggles-menu").hasClass( "active"))
    {
     //Do your transform, remove active class and assign inactive class
     }
    else{
     //Do your transform, remove inactive class and assign active class
    }
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```